# How to turn off or intercept Logcat logs?

Tags: android, logging, logcat

Strange enough problem...

Okay, here's my situation. In my Android application I'm using 3rd party component which generates a lot of Logcat logs. I don't have sources of those component :(

For some security reason I need to find way to somehow intercept those logs before they appearing in Logcat.

Is it possible? Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553146/disable-logcat-output-completely-in-release-android-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) on the 3rd party library to strip it of all calls to the Log class as per this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2019002/1122135

If the source code is available for the library, I would recommend building your own version of the library without the debug output.