# Disable Android Debug Log Messages for all apps

Tags: android

I own a Lenovo tablet that's constantly flooding the log with system (Android) debug messages, which complicates testing software on it.

Is there a way to disable all of androids debug log messages?

Comment: You should refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553146/disable-logcat-output-completely-in-release-android-app

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link, unfortunately it's unrelated, as I'm looking to completely disable any of the system logs.

Answer (score 1):

you can filter log messages.
In Android Studio: top-right of Android-Monitor "Show only selected apps" and left to it select the app you want to debug in the dropdown

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: Hello Björn, again, thank you for your advise. Unfortunately it does not solve the problem. Lenovo's Android build just floods the logs with messages causing messages from my apps to get lost. So what I'm actually looking for is a way to pipe all system messages to /dev/null - or something similar. By now, I've worked around the issue by avoiding the device for development, which, so far, seems to be the only solution. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When running the application, in the **Android bottom panel**--> **Show Only selected Apps**--> **Choose your package-name**

Also, since most of the device logs are of information level, **set the log level to errors**, to see if any error happens in your application.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. The problem is, that the logging is so extensive that messages show up in logcat seconds after they have been output. Sometimes messages even get lost - i.e. don't show up at logcat at all. So unfortunately, filtering the messages is not an option.