# Android Release build can be attached

Tags: android, build, release

I recently find my Android Release version can be attached through Android Studio and all logs are available to be seen as well, even though I'm sure that `AndroidManifest.xml` file doesn't contain `"android:debuggable=true"` and app's `build.gradle` file specified that

```
buildTypes {
...

release {
    ...
    debuggable false
    ...
}

...
}
```

Do you guys have any good idea to avoid this?

Comment: try to my code. please

Answer (score 0):

You can only keep like this code below:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

hopefully works it.

Comment: it will help you. Thanks :)

Comment: this configuration won't do anything with logs, the problem is different.

Comment: Agree with Avi:(

Answer (score 0):

Logs are nothing to do with `debuggable true.`

The option debuggale is to making your application debuggable in release mode, so you can attach debugger even on your release build by default it is false.

If you are using **Log** class and printing any log it will always display until and unless you put the check before logging them.

What you can do is put a check before every log is `Build.Debug == true` then print the log.

Or you can use open source library for this work like this [one](https://github.com/orhanobut/logger) which provide the control of logging based on your configuration.

Or you can find a more helpful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5553290/5585695).

Comment: Thanks, but why release build can still be attached then?

Comment: didn't follow you here, can you please explain what you want to know?

Comment: it is use for debug purpose.if your no need debug you can remove it easily. :)

Comment: I mean, I can still attach a release build via Android Studio. I assumed that release builds should be attached.

Comment: are you able to debug the release build even passing debuggable false?